# In which folder to install software on Linux

Tags: linux, installation

I'm trying to figure out which folder for what is on Linux. So I want to install a free ERP system. However I'm not sure in which folder I'm suppose to install it. Should it be in `\opt` or in `\srv`? The ERP system depends on other components such us java, for which I used `apt` to install it so I don't have much power regarding the installation directory, however I'm going to build the ERP from source, so I can decide where to put it.

Comment: Those folders vary from distro to distro. You could leave it in a subfolder of a user's home directory or use something like `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: Usually the software will have a default installation directory that results from running a command such as `make install` in the build tree. Usually it puts it in a "sane" place that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) should give you a better understanding of which folder is for what in Linux. It will, for example, make clear that it would not be `/srv` (data) but `/opt` (program). But you will still have a choice between e.g. `/opt` and `/usr/local/...`. Running `make install` would usually use `/usr/local/...`. When running an installer or unpacking a tarball, `/opt` is a common choice.